# TypeScript/RxJS - Appropriately handling observable error?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, observable

I am looking at [subscribe arguments](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments#what-signature-is-affected) from RxJS official documentation.
What is the use of `error: (e: string) => { ... }` when catching an error emitted by an observable? The program will still throw an `UnhandledPromiseRejection:` exception. However, encapsulating the entire `Subscription` object in a `try{}catch(...){}` statement runs appropriately. When it is necessary (or appropriately) to use `error` callback? Also, is there a way to have the progam execute correctly without using `try`/`catch`?

```js
import { Observable, lastValueFrom, Subscription, map } from "rxjs";
class Example {

    constructor() {
        this.start();
    }

    public async start() {
        console.log("===Start===");

        let x1$: Observable<number>;
        x1$ = new Observable((channel) => {
            channel.next(Math.random());
            setTimeout(() => {
                channel.error(`observable x1$ encountered an error`)
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(() => { channel.next(Math.random()) }, 200);
            setTimeout(() => { channel.next(Math.random()) }, 400);
            setTimeout(() => { channel.complete() }, 800);
        });

        try {
            let sub: Subscription = x1$.subscribe(
                {
                    next: (x: number) => {
                        console.log(x)
                    },
                    error: (error: string) => {
                        console.log(`the following error is caught: ${error}`);
                    },
                    complete: () => {
                        console.log()
                    }
                }
            );
            await lastValueFrom(x1$);//waits for the observable to complete
            sub.unsubscribe();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Catch clause error message: ${e}`)
        }
        
        console.log("===End===");
    }
}

let e: Example = new Example();
```

Output with `try`/`catch`:

```
===Start===
0.3822067117324466
the following error is caught: observable x1$ encountered an error
Catch clause error message: observable x1$ encountered an error
===End===
```

Output without `try`/`catch`:

```
===Start===
0.8635645928317222
the following error is caught: observable x1$ encountered an error
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by 
throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, 
or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
The promise rejected with the reason "observable x1$ encountered
an error".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

Comment: `lastValueFrom` creates a second subscription. The error handler of the first one is irrelevant for the second one.

Comment: @abetteroliver, more like a genius oliver. wow! That is so thoughtful and deep. I didn't realize this because I didn't know how `lastValueFrom()` was internally implemented. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a better oliver's comment, the issue is that `lastValueFrom(...)` will subscribe to the observable under the hood. It is left unchecked. The solution is to use `lastValueFrom(...).then(...).catch(...);` to appropriately handle the error.

```js
import {Observable, lastValueFrom, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
class CorrectExample {
    constructor() {
        this.start();
    }

    public async start() {
        console.log('===Start===');

        let x1$: Observable<number>;
        x1$ = new Observable((channel) => {
            channel.next(Math.random());
            setTimeout(() => {
                channel.error(`observable x1$ encountered an error`);
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(() => {
                channel.next(Math.random());
            }, 200);
            setTimeout(() => {
                channel.next(Math.random());
            }, 400);
            setTimeout(() => {
                channel.complete();
            }, 800);
        });

        let sub: Subscription = x1$.subscribe({
            next: (x: number) => {
                console.log(x);
            },
            error: (error: string) => {
                console.log(`the following error is caught: ${error}`);
            },
            complete: () => {
                console.log();
            }
        });
        sub.unsubscribe();

        //use then and catch after receiving the last element
        await lastValueFrom(x1$)
            .then((value: number) => {
                console.log(`The last element is ${value}`);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(`An error occurred when getting the last element: ${e}`);
            });

        console.log('===End===');
    }
}

let ce: CorrectExample = new CorrectExample();
```

Output:

```
===Start===
0.29472361796407065
An error occurred when getting the last element: observable x1$ encountered an error
===End===
```